# Add a hostname to a specific folder within Azure as another domain

Tags: azure, dns

So I have a project in azure that is www.example.com and it has it's MVC file structure with source code and all. However, within that, I have another part that needs it own URL, www.example2.com which would point to a folder within this hierarchy. So you could reach this entry point from www.example.com/#/example2.html or simply from going to www.example.com. Hope that makes sense. So within Azure, how can I achieve this? I am looking through custom domain, but not seeing a way to go about this. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using rewrite rules in your web.config. Adjust variables accordingly.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect domain" enabled="true">
         <match url="^(.*)$" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example2\.com$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="folder/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Don't forget to add and authorize both domains to your web app.